# What is the best proof that 1+1=2 by a person who was not Bertrand Russell?

Tags: logic, reference-request

The question says it all. Besides Russell and Whitehead, who are the philosophers and mathematicians who demonstrated successfully that 1+1=2? Extra bonus (i.e., a warm feeling inside) awarded for identifying the book or essay where the proof appears.

Comment: This question is slightly misguided. When you talk about a proof of something like that, you are really talking about proving it using the axiomatic method, right? But the axiomatic method in a completely formal setting wasn't initiated until Frege. Before then, people didn't care about providing a rigorous foundation of mathematics in the same way that they did afterwards. So you aren't going to find a book where people rigorously work out arithmetical identities based off of first principles in the same way they did.

Comment: Mauro's answer really points out another issue with the framing of this question. PM proves 1+1=2 in much the same way you do so in PA, how Dedekind and Peano did it, but it needs to prove much more first. PM isn't significant because it proved 1+1=2, it's significant because it was a full system of mathematical logic that was able to use a formal axiomatic method to prove all tautologies and many mathematical statements. Maybe you are really just concerned with who else has proven a very basic arithmetical identity, but I think this is a classic example of missing the forest for the trees.

Comment: It's too bad Kant went straight for 7+5=12. But Peano did one better, he spent four pages proving that 1 is a number and put Pythagoreans to shame. For they held that a number is a *multitude* of units, and hence the unit is *not* a number.

Comment: @Conifold - "Peano spent four pages proving that 1 is a number". Where ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Now that I think of it it was probably Couturat's retelling in Les  principes  des  mathematiques (1904), in Peano's formalism. Poincare makes fun of it in Les mathematiques et la logique (1905):"If it takes four pages to prove that 1 is a number how much would it take to prove a non-trivial theorem" (from memory).

Comment: @Conifold - Thanks. Maybe... in Peano's *Arithmetices principia* (linked below) **1 ∈ N** is *Axiomata 1* (page 1).

Comment: For what it is worth, here is my formal proof constructing the add function from Peano's Axioms and proving add(1,1)=2   http://www.dcproof.com/Add1plus1.htm (760 lines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a modern axiomatic approach, it follows from the **definition** of **2** as the *successor* of **1** :

> **2=s(1)** (also written : **2=1'**).

See Giuseppe Peano, [Arithmetices principia: nova methodo exposita (1889)](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog/page/n22), page 1.

The basic machinery was already in place in Richard Dedekind, [Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen ? (1893)](https://archive.org/details/wassindundwasso00dedegoog/page/n6), para.XI : **Addition of numbers** :

> *sum* is completely determined by the conditions
>
> > **m + 1 =m'**,
> >
> > **m + n' = (m + n)'**.

Applying the first condition to **m=1** we get :

> > **1+1=1'**.

---

Peano's approach is presumably derived from Leibniz's well-known proof of **2+2=4**.

See [New Essays on Human Understanding (1704)](https://books.google.it/books?id=vD6nSUSbL7IC&pg=PA414), Book IV, vii,10 [English transl, page 414] :

> *Definitions*. (1) *Two* is one and one.
>
> > (2) *Three* is two and one.
> >
> > (3) *Four* is three and one.

Leibniz introduces only one axiom for equality :

> *Axiom*. If equals be substituted for equals, the equality remains,

and thus the proof is incomplete, by modern standard, because it relies on the implicitly assumed *associativity* of sum.

---

Another source of Peano's work has been [Hermann Grassmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Grassmann).

Grassmann's *Lehrbuch der Mathematik* (1861) contains a reasonably complete axiom system for arithmetic.

See Hans-Joachim Petsche, [Hermann Grassmann : Biography](https://books.google.it/books?id=nWHeVXhUT2oC&pg=PA199), Birkhauser (2009), page 198-on.

Comment: That ''sum'' quoted section implies m+n'=(m+n)'=m'+n' where you subtract n' from both sides and you end up with m=m' LOL

Comment: @EternalPropagation - (m+n)'=m'+n' is wrong. The successor of (2+3) is 6 while the succesor of 2 is 3 and the successor of 3 is 4 and 3+4=7.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The link to Leibniz starts the text at p 515. Is the reference to p 414 correct?